# Cycle detected: Can I explicitly allow a circular dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, cycle

I'm working with a relatively large C#.NET codebase that is split into many different sub-projects, ultimately building into one single app. I recently added some functionality, but ended up creating a circular dependency:

My new module needs access to some existing functionality, and thus imports it. At the same time, the module I imported has a part which accesses some properties of the new module. As such, I have a circular dependency where two projects import each other respectively.

Rider, or rather the compiler, complains about it with error NU1108: Cycle detected.

In my opinion, that cycle is totally fine, I just can't get my project built. How can I deal with this dependency? Do I need to completely restructure the code?

Comment: i'm afraid your opinion doesn't matter much to the compiler. restructuring your project is the way to go - and usually, a clean project stucture brings its own merits, anyway

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Sure, the thing is I have absolutely no idea whatsoever how I should restructure it, given that, functionality-wise, the whole thing *is* circular. And since I don't "own" any of the other projects that I'm importing from I can't really change much in their either, which means I will end up with some weird hacky workaround, which feels even worse...

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Like the thing is, it would be completely fine if the two files were in the same project: The problem only appears because they are in different projects... So the workaround would be essentially copy pasting the entire "using" part from one project to the other, which would be so ugly...

Comment: @Fly, the solution is to introduce a 3rd project.  Things that both projects depend on should be in this project, and both projects should now reference the new project.